# How do I find a vector, that would give me a diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am not a native english speaker, so I don't really know how to explain the title in proper english terms. I have a equation:

$$A\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{u}$$

I know that $\mathbf{v}= (i, -1, i, -1)$ and $\mathbf{u}=(1+i, -i-1, i, -1)$.

How do I find $A$? I thought that maybe if I multiply both sides with such a vector $\mathbf{w}$ that would give me a $E$ (that being diagonal matrix with ones on the diagonal). But I cannot find such a vector.

Please help and excuse the fact that I cannot speak properly nor format properly.

Comment: Try to find a diagonal matrix $A$.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different martices such that $Av=w$.
You can try finding the easiest one.
Like *Exodd* suggested in his comment you can try finding a diagonal matrix.
If you take a general diagonal matrix: 
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
 x_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & x_2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & x_3 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & x_4
\end{pmatrix} $$
and you try multiplying it for $v$ you obtain an easy linear sistem $Av=w$
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
 x_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & x_2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & x_3 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & x_4
\end{pmatrix}   \begin{pmatrix}
 i \\ -1 \\ i \\ -1 
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
    1+i \\ -1-i \\i \\ -1 
\end{pmatrix}  $$
you can solve it and find $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$.

Comment: Ahhhh! Okay thank you!

Comment: If you find useful my answer, please select it as accepted one ^.^